# rollback with mulitple entity manager in java ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, transactions, entitymanager, rollback

In a web application with JBoss Application Server 7 and Container Managed Transaction, I have 2 persistence units, one for Oracle and one for PostgreSQL.  Then I inject two entity managers in a class.

In a method of this class that uses these entity mangers together, when a run-time exception is thrown that causes a rollback, only the Oracle data will rollback.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for us to help.

Comment: Formatting, capitalization

Answer (score 1):

Look for two-phase transactions.

You should prepare your databases for XA-transactions.

For PostgreSQL set parameter [max_prepared_transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PREPARED-TRANSACTIONS) to 10 for example.

For Oracle 9.2/10 grant rights for user:

```
grant select on sys.dba_pending_transactions to <user name>;
grant select on sys.pending_trans$ to <user name>;
grant select on sys.dba_2pc_pending to <user name>;
grant execute on sys.dbms_system to <user name>;
```

You should create XA-datasources in JBoss. My examples (make changes for your DB)

PostgreSQL:

```
        <driver name="postgresql-xa" module="org.postgresql">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>

            <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MoneyXADS" pool-name="MoneyXADS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                    127.0.0.1
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
                    5432
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
                    money
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>postgresql-xa</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                    <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                    <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                    <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
                </xa-pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>wassily</user-name>
                    <password>leontief</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </xa-datasource>
```

Oracle:

```
        <driver name="oracle-xa" module="com.oracle.db">
            <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>

            <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/CACCXADS" pool-name="CACCXADS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="User">
                    DEV_CACC
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="Password">
                    DEV_CACC
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>oracle-xa</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                    <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                    <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                    <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
                </xa-pool>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </xa-datasource>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i use jta transaction. can do than by jta transaction?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just set xa data sources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a *composite persistence unit* to connect with more databases. A composite persistence unit contains more composite unit *members*. One such composite persistence unit *member* is associated with each database. All composite persistence unit members are joined into *one* (integral) composite persiste unit. This composite unit is in Java linked to one @PersistenceContext. It operates according to one XA transaction.

In the elaborated answer, [Composite Persistence Unit solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699201/handle-multiple-entitymanager-in-java-ee-application/43786530#43786530), I explain how to comfigure two persistence unit members. Each composite persistence unit member is connected with a different database. You can use EclipseLink to configure composite persistence units: [CompositePersistenceUnits in EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite).